# How should I interpret the output of CGARCH Model in Eviews? C3, C4, C5, C6 and C7

Tags: interpretation, garch, volatility-forecasting, eviews, volatility

I am trying to understand how I should interpret the coefficients of CGARCH model. My topic is related to stock market volatility

[image]

Comment: Could you give the full title of the CGARCH model? Especially, could you explain what C stands for? (What GARCH stands for is clear.) Could you also include a link to EViews documentation for the CGARCH model?

Comment: Dear Richard, the model is Components GARCH